# deftype in defmacro with metadata

Tags: clojure

Let's suppose I have deftype looking next way:

```
(deftype ^{A: a} Name [])
```

I want define macro generating deftype:

```
(defmacro dotype [name]
  `(deftype ^{A :a} ~name []))
```

However, I'm losing information about metadata.

```
(macroexpand-1 '(dotype T))
;> (clojure.core/deftype T [])
```

I tried to use tricks with `vary-meta` to avoid using ^{} in macro. Unfortunately, `deftype` doesn't support IObj interface (doesn't support metadata), and all my tries didn't work.

Please suggest the way to implement this macro. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
(deftype A [])

(defmacro dotype [name]
  `(deftype ~(with-meta name {:tag A}) []))

(binding [*print-meta* true]
  (prn (macroexpand-1 '(dotype T))))

; user=> (clojure.core/deftype ^user.A T [])
```

Note: the metadata doesn't print by default, so you have to enable that by binding `*print-meta*` as shown above, or else set it in the REPL with `(set! *print-meta* true)`, but setting that permanently in the REPL will print a massive amount of uninteresting info to the screen, so best to avoid (!).